# How to make button disappear after function is called

Tags: javascript, html

I have a checkout page which has a function that displays products added to the cart. I made a function that, when refreshing the web page, clears items in the div. When clearing the div, it should hide the buy button because that button goes to the payment page and if there are no items it should not go to that page. So either make the button disappear or make sure that it goes to sproduct6.html if there are 0 items in div after clicking on the button.

Here is my whole checkout.html code:

```js
const cartItemsDiv = document.querySelector(".cart-items");
const storedCartItem = localStorage.getItem("selectedItems");
let subtotal = 0;

function clearCartItems() {
  localStorage.removeItem("selectedItems");
  const cartItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("selectedItems"));
}
// Make that it work and now it does not but it will just follow above

window.onload = clearCartItems; // Call the function on page load

if (storedCartItem) {
  const cartItem = JSON.parse(storedCartItem); // Parse the storedCartItem string into an array

  for (let i = 0; i < cartItem.length; i++) {
    const cartItemElement = document.createElement("div");

    cartItemElement.innerHTML = `
        <h3>${cartItem[i].title}</h3>  
        <p>Price: ${cartItem[i].price}</p>
        <p>License: ${cartItem[i].license}</p>
        <img src="${cartItem[i].image}" width='30%'/><br>
        <audio controls style="width:50%;">
          <source src="${cartItem[i].audio}" type="audio/mp3"> 
        </audio>
      `;
    // ADD DELETE OPTION 

    cartItemsDiv.appendChild(cartItemElement);

    const price = Number(cartItem[i].price.replace("$", "")); // Parse price as a number and remove dollar sign
    subtotal += price;
  }

  const subtotalElement = document.querySelector("#subtotal");
  subtotalElement.textContent = `$${subtotal.toFixed(2)}`;

  const totalElement = document.querySelector("#total");
  const total = subtotal;
  totalElement.textContent = `$${total.toFixed(2)}`;
  const totalPriceInput = document.querySelector("#total_price");
  totalPriceInput.value = total.toFixed(2);
}
```

```css
/* Styles for the cart items container */

#cart-items {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Styles for each product details container */

.product-details {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.product-details img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}


/* Styles for the product title */

.product-details h3:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}


/* Styles for the total price container */

#total {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Styles for the continue to payment button */

button {
  background-color: #4c5baf;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buy-btn {
  background-color: #4c5baf;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#buy-btn.non-active {
  display: block;
}


/* Styles for the continue to payment button when hovered */

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#audio {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}


/* FOUND OUT WHY IT CANT SCROLL IN MOBILE DEVICE AND FIX THAT BORDER IS RESIZED TO FULL MOBILE WIDTH,SAME AS FOR IPAD*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <h2 style="text-align:center;">Checkout</h2>
  <div id="cart-items">
    <p style="text-align:center;">YOU ADDED THIS PRODUCTS</p>
    <hr />
    <div class="product-container">
      <div class="cart-items"></div>
    </div>
    <button>Clear Items</button>
  </div>

  <div class="total">
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Subtotal: <br><span id="subtotal"></span></h3>
    <h3 style="text-align:center;">Total: <br><span id="total"></span></h3>
    <a href="http://localhost:4242"><button style="background-color: rgb(29, 4, 216);" id="buy-btn" class="non-active">Continue to payment</button></a>
    <!--Make next to eachself and red and blue color for button-->
    <a><button style="background-color: rgb(216, 4, 4);">Cancel</button></a>
    <!--Make next to eachself and red and blue color for button-->
  </div>
  <!--It does clear but wonder , make that you cant click on button if that function is done-->
</body>

</html>
```

I tried to first make it hide the buy button after div is cleared, then I tried to make that it goes to a specific URL, but I would better like someone to explain how to hide the button after the div is cleared.

Comment: Please format your code for readability and include the relevant html.

Comment: what is a [mcve]?

Comment: When you clear the DIV, remove the `non-active` class from the Buy button.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and reduce your code to a [mre] and read [ask]

Comment: Barmar - can you drop me code because I dont understand you!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, when your cart is in an empty state, you want to remove or prevent the submission of the buy button. Here are two ways to do this:

1. Toggle a class name to hide the button when the cart is empty.
2. Toggle a disabled property.

Here is a CodePen demonstrating both: https://codepen.io/Code2Empower/pen/jOeVboz

Both methods are shown here.

```
const enableButtons= () => {
  buy1.classList.remove('hidden');
  buy2.disabled = false;
}
const disableButtons= () => {
  buy1.classList.add('hidden');
  buy2.disabled = true;
}
```

To adapt this to your code you would enable the button when you add an item to the cart and you would disable it in the function that clears localStorage (which I believe you have named `ClearCartItems`).

As a best practice, I recommend not clearing the cart on page refresh. You can set an expiration token for time sensitive or stock limited items, but a typical user would not expect their cart to clear on refresh.